# PHP server times out when uploading a file that contains the text "function "

Tags: php, html, file-upload

Very strange...

When I upload a file that contains the string "function " the server times out and apparently my PHP script never runs.

My HTML form is simple:

```
<form action="serverCode.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="file" id="file">
<input type="submit" name="submitButton" value="Submit">
</form>
```

My PHP code does nothing but echo 'Hello':

```
<?php
echo 'Hello';
?>
```

Files that contain "unction " are OK - the script runs.
"function_" is OK - the script runs.

But if the file contains "function " (no quotes), my web browser times out waiting for a response.

What's going on here?

Comment: What is the file mime type you are uploading?

Comment: For the upload, HTTP Content-Type header is: multipart/form-data.  Is that what you're asking?  The problem happens when I upload both .html and .txt files.

Comment: What's in the server logs? Does Apache actually see the request coming in? What PHP version are you running? Have you enabled any 'hardening' plugins like Suhosin? What's the **exact** error you're getting on the timeout?

Comment: The logs that I have access to on the server (not mine, it is register.com) show nothing: no errors, no activity of any kind.  The client just times out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior is almost certainly due to some sort of web application firewall that is blocking the upload.

If you are hosting your own site, consider disabling security modules you have enabled.

If you are using an external web host, contact their support staff.

Comment: Psychic debugging: The firewall (or whatever security thing) might be looking for PHP or JS keywords. Terrible security strategy, but sounds distressingly plausible.

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly what I'm guessing is happening here. It's crude for sure, but also quite common. :/

Comment: This makes sense.  I am not hosting my own site; I will contact the support staff and see if they'll confirm this.

Comment: Confirmed.  From the host: "This is a security feature on our hosting there is no work around for this".  How frustrating!  Thanks all for your help.

Comment: Time for a better web host? :)